# How to calculate leave balance if I have Total Allotted Leaves column for each employee?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have empdetails table with column as allotted leaves. I have an extra column for `LeavesTaken`. Now I want to calculate leave balance of each employee and update it accordingly.

`````
        {
            command.Connection = _connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            List<Users.LeaveRequest> leaves = new List<Users.LeaveRequest>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                leaves.Add(new Users.LeaveRequest() { DayPart = reader.GetInt32(3), fromdate = reader["fromdate"].ToString(), todate = reader["todate"].ToString() });
            }
            reader.Close();
            if (leaves.Count>0)
            {
                leaveRequests = leaves;
            }
            else
            {
                leaveRequests = null;
            }

            command.CommandText = "SELECT TotalLeaves,LeavesTaken FROM empDetails WHERE empID = @empid";
            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", CurrentUser.Employee.EmpID);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                employee.TotalLeaves = reader.GetInt32(0);
                employee.LeavesTaken = reader.GetDouble(1);
            }
            reader.Close();
            return employee;
        }````
`````

Comment: can you please post sample database

Comment: `LeaveBalance = TotalLeaves - LeavesTaken `.

Comment: Why would you want to update it in the table? You have an AllotedLeaves column and a LeavesTaken column, so you can calculate the balance to show in an application at any time. Please show some sample data and clarify exactly what it is you need.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three solutions, since you didn't specify precisely what you want, neither sample data:

1. You want to total values for an employee:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(TotalLeaves), SUM(LeavesTaken)
   FROM empDetails 
   WHERE empID = @empid
   ```
2. You want balance between the two values

   ```
   SELECT SUM(TotalLeaves) - SUM(LeavesTaken)
   FROM empDetails 
   WHERE empID = @empid
   ```
3. If you have one record per `empID`, you could also try:

   ```
   SELECT TotalLeaves - LeavesTaken
   FROM empDetails 
   WHERE empID = @empid
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about why you have Integer for your total leaves, but anyway you can have the calculation be done in `CommandText`

Assuming these three columns `AllottedLeaves, TotalLeaves, LeavesTaken` have the datatype of `DECIMAL(4,2)`

> Now I want to calculate leave balance of each employee and update it accordingly.

1. Update **all** employee in `TABLE empDetails`

   ```
   {
       command.CommandText = "UPDATE empDetails " + 
                             "SET TotalLeaves = TotalLeaves - llottedLeaves, " +
                             "LeavesTaken = LeavesTaken + AllottedLeaves, " +
                             "AllottedLeaves = 0" +
                             "WHERE AllottedLeaves <> 0 AND AllottedLeaves <= TotalLeaves";
       command.Connection = _connection;
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```
2. Update **one** employee in `TABLE empDetails`

   ```
   {
       command.CommandText = "UPDATE empDetails " + 
                             "SET TotalLeaves = TotalLeaves - llottedLeaves, " +
                             "LeavesTaken = LeavesTaken + AllottedLeaves, " +
                             "AllottedLeaves = 0" +
                             "WHERE empID = @empid";
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", CurrentUser.Employee.EmpID);
       command.Connection = _connection;
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```